Can't run Hibernate in a module environment
The problem
I'm having trouble trying to make Hibernate run in a project that have modules. I am trying to modernize an old tool that uses and old version of Hibernate with javax-based JPA and I am trying to migrate it to a newer version and make it jakarta-based.
Long story short, it fails with ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to instantiate the HibernatePersistenceProvider class due to some module problem when handling JBoss Logging. The tool use the HibernatePersistenceProvider to call the createContainerEntityManagerFactory method.
In order to isolate the problem, I built a MCVE.
MCVE
I'm using Gradle 8.10.2 and Java 23. All the other package versions are in the gradle.build file.
This is the build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("project-report")
}

description = "MCVE for a problem in Hibernate"
group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

def artifactName = "com.example"
def moduleName = "com.example"

def versionApiguardian = "1.1.2"
def versionHibernate   = "7.0.0.Beta1"
def versionJakartaAnno = "3.0.0"
def versionJakartaCdi  = "4.1.0"
def versionJakartaEl   = "6.0.1"
def versionJakartaInj  = "2.0.1"
def versionJakartaInt  = "2.2.0"
def versionJakartaJpa  = "3.2.0"
def versionJakartaJta  = "2.0.1"
def versionJBossLog    = "3.6.1.Final"
def versionJunit       = "5.11.2"
def versionJunitPlatf  = "1.11.2"

dependencies {

    // Jakarta, JPA and friends.
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.annotation" , name: "jakarta.annotation-api"       , version: versionJakartaAnno)
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.enterprise" , name: "jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api"   , version: versionJakartaCdi )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.enterprise" , name: "jakarta.enterprise.lang-model", version: versionJakartaCdi )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.persistence", name: "jakarta.persistence-api"      , version: versionJakartaJpa )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.transaction", name: "jakarta.transaction-api"      , version: versionJakartaJta )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.inject"     , name: "jakarta.inject-api"           , version: versionJakartaInj )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.interceptor", name: "jakarta.interceptor-api"      , version: versionJakartaInt )
    testImplementation(group: "jakarta.el"         , name: "jakarta.el-api"               , version: versionJakartaEl  )

    // JUnit.
    testImplementation(group: "org.junit.platform", name: "junit-platform-launcher", version: versionJunitPlatf )
    testImplementation(group: "org.junit.jupiter" , name: "junit-jupiter-api"      , version: versionJunit      )
    testImplementation(group: "org.junit.jupiter" , name: "junit-jupiter-params"   , version: versionJunit      )
    testImplementation(group: "org.junit.jupiter" , name: "junit-jupiter-engine"   , version: versionJunit      )
    testImplementation(group: "org.apiguardian"   , name: "apiguardian-api"        , version: versionApiguardian)

    // Hibernate.
    testImplementation(group: "org.hibernate.orm", name: "hibernate-core", version: versionHibernate)

    // JBoss Logging.
    testImplementation(group: "org.jboss.logging", name: "jboss-logging", version: versionJBossLog)
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.debug = true
    options.fork = true
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs += [
            "--module-path", classpath.asPath
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    defaultCharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

And, here is the /src/test/java/module-info.java file:
open module com.example {
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires jakarta.persistence;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
}

And here is the /src/test/java/com/example/SomeTest.java file:
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        // Instantiating the first parameter is difficult, so, test for NPE
        // just to be sure we didn't got ExceptionInInitializerError.
        NullPointerException npe = Assertions.assertThrows(
                NullPointerException.class,
                () -> new HibernatePersistenceProvider().createContainerEntityManagerFactory(null, new HashMap<>())
        );
        Assertions.assertTrue(npe.getMessage().contains("getPersistenceUnitName()"));
    }
}

Running that with this command line:
gradle build --info

Will produce this inside all the output:
SomeTest > testIt() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown, expected: <java.lang.NullPointerException> but was: <java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError>
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:67)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3128)
        at app/com.example/com.example.SomeTest.testIt(SomeTest.java:12)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example/com.example.SomeTest.lambda$testIt$0(SomeTest.java:13)
            at org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:53)
            ... 3 more

            Caused by:
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This library does not have private access to interface org.hibernate.internal.EntityManagerMessageLogger
                at org.jboss.logging@3.6.1.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2572)
                at org.jboss.logging@3.6.1.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2552)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.<clinit>(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:42)
                ... 5 more

1 test completed, 1 failed

Trying to downgrade JBoss-Logging to 3.5.0.Final (which is the version declared as a dependency for Hibernate 7.0.0.Beta1 accordingly to this) will give a different error instead:
SomeTest > testIt() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown, expected: <java.lang.NullPointerException> but was: <java.lang.IllegalAccessError>
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:67)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3128)
        at app/com.example/com.example.SomeTest.testIt(SomeTest.java:13)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jboss.logging.JBossLogRecord (in module org.jboss.logging) cannot access class java.util.logging.LogRecord (in module java.logging) because module org.jboss.logging does not read module java.logging
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1026)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1103)
            at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:741)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:665)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:528)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.JDKLoggerProvider.getLogger(JDKLoggerProvider.java:29)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.logProvider(LoggerProviders.java:150)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.tryJDK(LoggerProviders.java:106)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.findProvider(LoggerProviders.java:101)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:32)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.<clinit>(LoggerProviders.java:29)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2465)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2573)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
            at org.jboss.logging@3.5.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@7.0.0.Beta1/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.<clinit>(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:42)
            at com.example/com.example.SomeTest.lambda$testIt$0(SomeTest.java:15)
            at org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:53)
            ... 3 more

1 test completed, 1 failed

Trying to downgrade Hibernate to 6.6.1.Final either with JBoss Logging 3.5.0.Final or 3.6.1.Final doesn't work and gives very similar errors.
The best case was with Hibernate 6.6.1.Final and JBoss Logging 3.6.1.Final when the error comes from the createContainerEntityManagerFactory method instead of the HibernatePersistenceProvider constructor:
SomeTest > testIt() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown, expected: <java.lang.NullPointerException> but was: <java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError>
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:67)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
        at app/org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3128)
        at app/com.example/com.example.SomeTest.testIt(SomeTest.java:13)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:35)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:102)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:169)
            at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:142)
            at com.example/com.example.SomeTest.lambda$testIt$0(SomeTest.java:15)
            at org.junit.jupiter.api@5.11.2/org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:53)
            ... 3 more

            Caused by:
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This library does not have private access to interface org.hibernate.internal.EntityManagerMessageLogger
                at org.jboss.logging@3.6.1.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2572)
                at org.jboss.logging@3.6.1.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2552)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
                at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:142)
                ... 9 more

1 test completed, 1 failed

The workaround
As a proof of concept, if I sacrifice modularity, remove the module-info.java file and comment out the doFirst block in the gradle.build file, it works!
However, I can't really sacrifice modularity in my environment.
My questions

Maybe I should add something to the module-info.java file?
Or maybe I should change the version of some package?
Or perhaps add some --add-opens command line options somewhere in gradle.build?
Or should I avoid to ever directly instantiate HibernatePersistenceProvider and it was no more than an accident that this ever worked?
Is this a bug in Hibernate?

Or put simply:

What I am doing wrong?
How can I fix this?
Any ideas?

I tried a lot of things to fix this issue, and other than just throwing modularity out of the window, nothing worked so far.

The latest Hibernate is Hibernate 6.6.1.Final; Hibernate 7.0 is still in development, as made clear by the "Beta1" in the version. So if you're looking to update an application, use a released version, not a development milestone.

@MarkRotteveel Downgrading Hibernate doesn't work either (I already was so given up of that, that I didn't even considered going back when I wrote the question). Anyway, for the sake of completude, I edited the question and added that case. Funny note: It gets a little bit better with Hibernate 6.6.1.Final and JBoss Logging 3.6.1.Final, enough to pass the simple new HibernatePersistenceProvider() but still crashes down the road, so I also edited the test to not be so naive.
